# Magento - updating orders and customer notification

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Within Magento orders, there is the option to send the customer a notification to update them of the status

I have some orders that `Processing`, but i cannot seem to update them to any other status.

I'd like to add custom status's so I can send the customer a notification.

In the drop down i could select `Warehouse`, which would notify the customer their order is in the warehouse

How would I do this?

I'm using v1.6.2

Thanks

Comment: Custom order statuses can be configured in the backend, System > Order Statuses

Comment: That's exactly how i did it. Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom order statuses can be created in the backend, under System > Order Statuses.

1. Create New Status
2. Assign it to a State

[image: Screenshot of Order statuses screen]

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the "state" notion of magento, as the "status" notion has been written to allow specifics and detailed states.

To create and link (to an existing and native magento state) your status, you should add a portion of code in the "config.xml" file of your module, something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    [...]

    <global>

        [...]

        <sales>

            [...]

            <order>

                [...]

                <!-- Statuses declaration -->
                <statuses>
                    <avaiblable_in_warehouse translate="label">
                        <label>Avaiblable in Warehouse</label>
                    </avaiblable_in_warehouse>
                </statuses>
                <!-- Linking Status to a state -->
                <states>
                    <processing>
                        <statuses>
                            <avaiblable_in_warehouse />
                        </statuses>
                    </processing>
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: This isn't necessary in version 1.6.2. Custom order statuses can be configured in the backend w/o modifying any config.xml

Comment: Yes, but this way, when you will deploy your application, you just add an other boring manipulation...

Comment: I had a look at the order statuses. If I create a new one and then assign it to `Processing`, in the Order History drop-down in the order, it let's me change the status. this is exactly what I'm looking to do.